# Python replace() in XML file

Tags: python, xml, replace

I am facing with another problem.

I have kind of XML file with example code:

```
<case classname="perf" name="device">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case>

<case2 name="device_n>
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>yyy</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case2>

<case...n>
...
</case...n>
```

How can I replace xxx to be named 'device' and yyy in case2 to be device_n?

I think something like that could be OK, but don't know how to write it:

```
with open('some_xml.xml') as parsed:
    if line in parsed.readlines.startswith("name="):
        line.replace('', "name=... #what's now?
```

This should be somekind of iterator because I have a lot of cases.

Comment: In case 3 the replacement of yyy is device_n or device_3?

Comment: did you tried your code ? It makes no sense. `readlines` is a function which neads `()`. `readlines()` gives list and list doesn't have `startswith()`. String has function `startswith()`  but `name=` is not at the beginning of the line so checking `startswith("name=")` makes no sense. Other problem is that `xxx` is in diffferent line then "name=" so you can't use replace in the same `line`.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more clever way to do this with regex, but basic string searching seems to work:

```
import io

data = '''
<case classname="perf" name="device">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case>

<case2 name="device_n">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>yyy</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case2>'''

strOut="" # new string
f = io.StringIO(data)  # load string data as file text
for rowx in f:  # each line in data
    row = rowx.rstrip()  # remove newline
    if ' name="' in row: # <case name=...>
        nm = row[row.index(' name="')+7:len(row)-2] # get name
    if "<Name>" in row and nm:  # <Name>....
        idx = row.index("<Name>") + 6
        strOut += row[:idx] + nm + "</Name>\n"  # set name field here
        nm = ""  # in case bad block, don't copy wrong name
    else:
        strOut += row + "\n"  # copy line to new string

print(strOut)
```

Output

```
<case classname="perf" name="device">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>device</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case>

<case2 name="device_n">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>device_n</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case2>
```

Comment: And the last question, how to make your script to change (according to my first post) from `name="device"` to `name='xxx'` vice versa?

Comment: I updated the answer, see the comment `set name field here`

Comment: Yep, thanks, but when I change the `</Name>\n` to `' name="'` it still doesn't work.

Comment: `</Name>\n` is the end tag. Don't change that. If you want a different name, change the `nm` variable: `strOut += row[:idx] + "MyNewName" + "</Name>\n"`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach (using xml parsing)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

to_replace = {".//case/Name":'device',".//case2/Name":'device_n'}
xml = '''<r>
<case classname="perf" name="device">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case>

<case2 name="device_n">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>yyy</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>

 </case2>
  </r>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for x_path,new_val in to_replace.items():
  ele = root.find(x_path)
  ele.text = new_val
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<r>
<case classname="perf" name="device">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>device</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>
</case>

<case2 name="device_n">
    <Type>GET</Type>
    <Name>device_n</Name>
    <Request>Something</Request>

 </case2>
  </r>
```